# How to remove the leading 0 and the last 0 in this code?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to write a program that asks for user input of a positive integer larger than 2. The program is supposed to output all the positive integers that are smaller than the user input and that are multiples of 3. However, when running my code I noticed there are two annoying 0’s that keep appearing and aren’t supposed to be there. Any help on how to remove them or make the code better? Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int get_numbers(int x) 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i += 3) 
    {
      cout << i << " ";
    }
return 0;
  
}

int main() 
{
  int integer = 0;
  cout << "Enter a positive integer larger than 2: ";
  cin >> integer;
  cout << get_numbers(integer);
}
```

Comment: *I am attempting to write a program* Don't sell yourself short. You ARE writing a program. It just doesn't work right yet.

Comment: `get_numbers` always returns `0`. What do you expect `cout << get_numbers(integer)` to print, other than `0`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's walk through your code and explain it. There are 2 important parts that have `cout`:

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i += 3) 
{
  cout << i << " ";
}
```

What does this loop mean? Well

1. Start `i` at **0**
2. Go while `i` is less than `x`
3. Increment `i` by 3
4. Print every `i`.

The important part is `1`. You are starting `i` at 0, you will print 0. To fix this, don't start at 0! Start at a different number (probably 3 from your description of the desired behaviour).

---

The other cout is here:

```
cout << get_numbers(integer);
```

You are printing the return of the function `get_numbers`. If you look in that function, it only returns 1 thing:

```
return 0;
```

So you are going to print **0**!

This function doesn't need to return anything, so just do:

```
void print_numbers_in_increments_of_3(int x);
```

And remove the `cout`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the zeroes aren't just appearing.
You put them there on purpose.

First zero is in your loop - you start at 0, and print `i` every iteration.

You should instead start with 3:

```
for (int i = 3; i < x; i += 3) 
{
  cout << i << " ";
}
```

Don't worry about numbers smaller than 3, the loop just won't be executed at all, which is ok, nothing will be printed.

Your second (last) zero comes from this line:

```
cout << get_numbers(integer);
```

You print the value `get_numbers` returns.

Except there is no reason for it to return a value, and there is no reason for you to print it.

So just remove `cout <<` from than line, and change `get_numbers` to be of type `void` instead of `int`.

Also, get rid of `return 0`.